# Is there a component/method that can take any signal, then increase it to 5 volts no matter how small the signal is?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, logic-level

I was using a logic level MOSFET that should turn on when a voltage other than 0 volts between two points is detected. My problem is that the voltage is at times less than 5 volts and probably won't activate my logic level MOSFET. I need to know if there's such a component that takes any input voltage (0.1V or higher) then outputs 5 volts unless the voltage is 0.

Comment: Sounds like you want an op amp? How close to 0 is too close to 0? Is 0.01V enough to trigger it? 0.001? 1V?

Comment: Will that work? I want it to be constantly 5V, I don't know if an op-amp can do that; the output might exceed 5V. I want to amplify voltages from at least 0.1V. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: A comparator???

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you want to answer with that, because thats what I was about to do. A comparator with 100 mv accuracy is exactly what op wants

Comment: @Passerby okay.

Comment: I forgot about comparators, damn hahaha. Thanks for the answers

Comment: @TTbulaski don't forget to accept DKN's answer

Comment: perhaps you're looking for a data slicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a comparator, which is basically an op-amp optimized to provide as much gain as possible under all circumstances; So much gain that it provides maximum or minimum output and hits its power rail.

Use a reference input of 100mV on the inverting input and apply your signal to the non-inverting input.

In other words, it just outputs a HI when the voltage of one input terminal is higher than the other, and outputs a LO otherwise.

Comment: Be aware many comparators have open-drain or open-collector outputs and this isn't always obvious in the datasheet if you don't know to look for it. If you use one of these you'll need a pull-up resistor to 5 V on the output.